# Is there a way to use the Xlsxwriter "write_formula" function to apply it to whole column rather than each cell?

Tags: xlsxwriter

I am using the [write_formula](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/worksheet.html#write_formula) method from [Xlsxwriter](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/index.html) module in Python to calculate some values. However what I have noticed is that I have to write per cell. As the method does not accept a range of cells.

What I want to achieve is to be able to have the formula stored for all the rows in the specific column, this includes rows where there is no data as well, so for example the whole excel range (2: 1048546).

At the moment I have achieved this by looping through a range like so:

```
for i in range(2, 1048546):
    str_i = f"A{i}"
    formula = "=SUM(1, 2)"
    worksheet.write_formula(f"B{i}", formula=formula, value=0)
```

But as mentioned I would like to do it for the whole column, so I can skip the time consuming for loop. I did something similar using the data_validation method like so:

```
worksheet.data_validation(
    "L2:L1048546",
    {"validate": "list", "source": ["value1", "value2"]},
)
```

But the `data_validation` accepts the range of values unlike the `write_formula` method. I also tried it with the range for the `write_formula` method like so:

```
worksheet.write_formula(
    "H2:H1048546",
    "SUM(1, 2)",
    value=0
)
```

But this only wrote the data for where rows have values.

Is there another way to get the `write_formula` to work the same way `data_validation` works?

Comment: Using a range "H2:H1048546" would only write the formula to 'H2' as that is the only part of the range that would be extracted.

Comment: The 'write_formula', and 'write' methods, indeed all write methods (write_string, write_number etc) use the 'convert_cell_args' method and extracts just one cell coordinate. 'data_validation' uses the @convert_range_args method and extracts a range. So write_formula will only extract a single cell in either row/column or A1 notation. If you were to use `worksheet.write({cell}, '=SUM(1, 2)')` or `worksheet.write_string({cell}, '=SUM(1, 2)')` you'd would have the same issue

Comment: Ok so seems the for-loop is the only way to achieve this in the end?